# Coming out of screen-lock, sometimes my machine will sleep/lock 30 seconds after

Tags: sleep-wake, bug, screen-lock

I haven't pinpointed any potential triggers yet, but sometimes when I come out of sleep or from having a locked screen, after typing my password in and re-entering the OS, about 20 or 30 seconds later, the screen just shuts off and goes to sleep.

I almost always use an external monitor, but can't remember if this ever happens w/out it connected.

One thing that *does* happen every time is that the password box is missing its blue highlight. My keyboard focus is still inside of it though.  When I see this, 100% of the time, this re-lock/sleep happens.

I'm running 10.8.2 mountain lion.

Any ideas on what is causing this, or anyone else experience this?

Comment: I have the same issue from time to time. Mine first appeared when i upgraded to an SSD and installed Mountain Lion, but i have never managed to work out which of these are the cause. I suspect it's a power management issue with the 3rd party SSD.

Comment: I'm also running a 3rd party SSD (with ML). I have TRIM enabled. You?

Comment: Have you tried 10.8.3? It just came out!

Comment: I don't have TRIM enabled. Just an OCZ Vertex 4 with no special tweaks.

Comment: I just updated to 10.8.3. Hopefully they buried a fix for this in there..There was one fix regarding "display issues coming out of sleep" I think.. will follow up on this.

Comment: I'm on 10.8.3 and still have this problem.

Comment: I'm on Mavericks 10.9.3 now and I no longer have the problem.